# Install module to site-packages with setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to upload a CLI to PIP that, once installed, will run when the user types `myscript`

My folder structure is like this:

```
lib
  myscript
    __init__.py (empty)
    __main__.py (code that needs to run)
    utilities.py (needs to be imported from main)

scripts
  myscript

setup.py
```

My `setup.py` should install the `lib.myscript` package and install `myscript` as a command-line module

#### `setup.py`

```py
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='myscript',
    version='1.0',
    scripts=['./scripts/myscript'],
    packages=['lib.myscript'],
    install_requires=['setuptools', 'pandas >= 0.22.0', 'numpy >= 1.16.0'],
    python_requires='>=3.5'
)
```

#### `scripts/myscript`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ! $@ ]]; then
    python -m myscript -h
else
    python -m myscript $@
fi
```

Once I do `python setup.py install`, `myscript` is installed as a command-line module and it runs. However, it throws an error saying that there is no module named `myscript`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't install `myscript`, you've installed `lib.myscript` so try this: `python -m lib.myscript`. And for Python to recognize `lib` as a package create an empty file `lib/__init__.py`.

PS. This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ! $@ ]]; then
    python -m myscript -h
else
    python -m myscript $@
fi
```

could be simplified as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec python -m myscript ${@:--h}
```

which in shell-speak means "Use `$@` if not empty, else `-h`"

Comment: For Python to recognize `lib` as a package create an empty file `lib/__init__.py`.