# How to run a Python module from any directory

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to create a module called `myscript` that can be run via the command line from any directory.

I've created a `setup.py` file that looks like this:

```py
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='myscript',
    version='1.0',
    packages=['lib.myscript'],
    install_requires=['setuptools', 'pandas >= 0.22.0', 'numpy >= 1.16.0'],
    python_requires='>=3.5'
)
```

After running `python setup.py install`, I'm still unable to run `python -m myscript` from anywhere but the directory the script is located in.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
lib
  myscript
    __init__.py (empty)
    __main__.py (the code that should run)

setup.py
```

Comment: What about `python -m lib.myscript`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install module to site-packages with setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56552410/install-module-to-site-packages-with-setuptools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to set `entry_points` function in `setup.py` (and if I understood your question correctly).

Your `setup.py` becomes:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='myscript',
    version='1.0',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=['setuptools', 'pandas >= 0.22.0', 'numpy >= 1.16.0'],
    python_requires='>=3.5'
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myscript=myscript.__main__:main' # or any specific function you would like
        ]
    },
)
```

Here `__main__` is a filename (in your case). And `main` is a function (you can change it to whatever function you would like). And `myscript` is your command.

Now you can run (maybe `myscript` in your case):

```
python -m pip install yourpackage
```

Then you can run your script from anywhere:

```
myscript
```

edit:

arrange your file structure like:

```
myscript
  myscript
    __init__.py (empty)
    __main__.py (the code that should run)
  setup.py
```

Comment: I used the exact `setup.py` you provided and ran `python setup.py install` and `python -m pip install myscript`, but I still get a python error saying `No module named myscript`

Comment: param, I edited my answer, also you have to modify the `setup.py` file as per your needs, also you may want to clean the pip cache before installing